# Merge tags [mediarecorder] and [android-mediarecorder]

Tags: support, tags, retag-request

I propose to merge the [mediarecorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediarecorder) (585 question) with the [android-mediarecorder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-mediarecorder) (517 questions) into the android-mediarecorder. The mediarecorder is only referring to android:

> Mediarecorder is the Android class used for recording Audio and Video
>   available since API Level 1.

Comment: I read that as _"mediocre coder"_... now I'm disappointed.

Comment: Weird, I've already answered a few [mediarecorder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mediarecorder+javascript) questions that were not at all about Android (it was about the [web-API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder)). But I also notice that there is a [tag:web-mediarecorder] and even a [tag:mediarecorder-api] tag, with no excerpt.